# im trying to test range values of 2d arrays but it keeps looping

Tags: java

I have 12 points in groups of 3. I want to test to see if each of the 12 points of my array are between 395 and 405. Then I want to test if all 3 points in a group is under 400. If true then output message, but my code keeps looping continuously. Can someone check it for me please?

```
tempi=i;
tempx=x;
for( i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    for( x=0;x<4;x++)
    {
        if(rounded[i][x]<395 || rounded[i][x] >405)
        {
            System.out.println("there is an error with probes "+rounded[i][x]);
        }
        else if(values[i=0][x]< 400)
        {
            System.out.println("all points in element "+tempi+"as they are below 400 needs replaced("+"point "+tempx+" : "+values[i][x]+")");                       
        }
        else if(values[i=1][x]<400)
        {
            System.out.println("all points in element "+tempi+"as they are below 400 needs replaced("+"point "+tempx+" : "+values[i][x]+")");
        }
        else if(values[i=2][x]<400)
        {
            System.out.println("all points in element "+tempi+"as they are below 400 needs replaced("+"point "+tempx+" : "+values[i][x]+")");
        }
    }           
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In these lines you are re-setting the value of i. So it makes sense that you would never exit the loop.

```
else if(values[i=0][x]< 400)
....
else if(values[i=1][x]<400)
....
else if(values[i=2][x]<400)
```

I think what you want is something along the lines of:

```
else if(i == 0 && values[i][x]< 400)
....
else if(i == 1 && values[i][x]<400)
....
else if(i == 2 && values[i][x]<400)
```

Comment: that works thanks but do i actualy need the nested for loops or would it run without

Comment: For 2d arrays you typically do need nested loops.

Answer (score 1):

On each iteration you're saying

```
(values[i=0][x]< 400)
```

etc, resetting your i value to 0,1, and 2 respectively. You may be wanting to use i-0 or i+0. If you're checking for equality, use ==